# Using a key pair how do I decrypt a message given letters were represented by ASCII values?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ascii, key-pair

The key pairs are both prime numbers.

This was all the information I was given and researching this hasn't been too clear either.

Comment: Please provide more info and some code with your question

Comment: Which letters? Those of the plaintext or the ciphertext? Without programming this is not on topic on SO.